# g++ can't find headers even when it's specified

Tags: c++, g++, makefile

So basically I have some really simple code that includes `<BigIntegerLibrary.hh>` which resides in `/Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint`. I was compiling with this:

`g++ main.cpp -o Main -I/Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint`

but it reported a fatal error that it could not find the file. Am I doing it right? Thanks!

`main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'BigIntegerLibrary.hh' file not found`

Comment: have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: Yes, I have, it worked but I can't find out why this couldn't.

Comment: @TrevorHickey Isn't it what he just showed?

Comment: @H2CO3 was thinking "C:\..."

Comment: @TrevorHickey Deducing from the context, this seems OS X, not Windows. Windows uses backslashes, not slashes, and the GNU toolchain is typically disused on Windows.

Comment: How do you quote include directive? You should not use angle brackets if absolute path.

Comment: do `ls /Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint/BigIntegerLibrary.hh` and type the result here

Comment: `// This header file includes all of the library header files.

#include "NumberlikeArray.hh"
#include "BigUnsigned.hh"
#include "BigInteger.hh"
#include "BigIntegerAlgorithms.hh"
#include "BigUnsignedInABase.hh"
#include "BigIntegerUtils.hh"` The file is there D:

Comment: also try to add slash at the end, but not sure this can matter

Comment: may be some configuration file overrides the setting

Comment: I was using the Terminal, is there such a file?

Comment: @Yoshi not familiar so close

Comment: Try verbose mode, may be it tell some hints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
#include "BigIntegerLibrary.hh"
```

If you specify the *#included* file with angle brackets (`#include <includeFile.h>`) the compiler will try to find it in a predefined location whereas if you use `#include "includeFile"` the compiler first tries the paths you specified with the `-I` compiler option.

The `-I` compiler option cannot be used to specify where the `<...>` files are.

Comment: Are you sure you have the case of the letters in the path right? Did you double check with `ls /Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint/BigIntegerLibrary.hh`?

Comment: Yup, double checked. When I did a `cat` on the path it showed the contents.

Comment: -I can change where <...> files are, it modifies the search path. Evidence: the manual, and that it works on my system.

Answer (score 0):

If the path is correct `g++` should see the files.

If you use absolute path in include directive, you should change quotation:

```
#include "/Users/wen/Projects/include/bigint/BigIntegerLibrary.hh"
```

Comment: I did change it when I used absolute, but now if I use any kind of bracket it won't work when I use -I<path>.

Comment: double check the path; it should work if it is correct and readeable